# Base ten is called "decimal"; what's the name of numbers in base 15?

Tags: terminology, number-systems

Good afternoon all, I was wondering is there a **table of names** for the base x of numbers?

For example, I know that numbers in base 10 are called "decimal", those in base 2 are called "binary", base 16 is called "hexadecimal", but what will be the name for those in *base 9*, or *base 15* ?

Comment: it has no real name you could expand the latin (or was it greek?) to other numbers (pentadecimal) but I doubt it will catch on, no-one uses base 15 or base 9 enough for it to get a name

Comment: See [other bases in human language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation). Also, I give lessons on how to use Google...

Comment: I have heard the term **quindecimal** but looking in Google now shows that (although it can be used for base 15) it is primarily used for a certain 15-note musical scale.

Comment: About typography: please omit the hyphen after "base"; in that position it could be taken (as I did) for a minus sign. [Positional number systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation#Non-standard_positional_numeral_systems) with negative bases do exist!

Comment: Your title should say "base 2" or "base two" in reference to binary, not "base 10" (which ordinarily means "base ten"); i.e., "base 10" is *not* ordinarily called "binary".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nonary and pentadecimal respectively.

You might also be interested in the Wikipedia articles that give the [names for n-ary bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numeral_systems#Standard_positional_numeral_systems) and the article on [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix), which is another name for 'base'.

Comment: There's a convention that when new words are coined, one doesn't mix Latin with Greek. This is sometimes violated, e.g., in "automobile," where "auto-" is Greek but "-mobile" is Latin. But since GEdgar points out that quindecimal does have some currency, that would be a reason to prefer quindecimal rather than pentadecimal. Here is some information about Greek and Latin number prefixes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_prefix Google ngram viewer http://books.google.com/ngrams shows zero hits for both words in books since 1800, which suggests that there simply isn't a commonly accepted word.

Comment: @BenCrowell I'd err slightly in the other direction, for two reasons: (a) 'pentadecimal' is consistent with 'hexadecimal' which also mixes Greek and Latin, and (b) a Google [verbatim search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1734130) shows five times more hits for 'pentadecimal' than for 'quindecimal'. But I agree that there is little consensus, and for that reason it probably doesn't matter which you use. As an aside, my favourite example of a mixed Greek-Latin root is 'television' :)

Comment: And also polyamory.  That's why polyamory is wrong.