# Why is base-10 decimal?

Tags: soft-question, number-systems, convention

A way to write a number in various bases is: 101<sub>2</sub>, 3Fa<sub>16</sub>, 519<sub>10</sub>.

The thing here, is that we apparently specify the base in decimal by default. This makes sense in everyday life, since we're not really doing base conversion when grocery shopping. But `10` is ambiguous when working with different bases. So why is 101<sub>10</sub> not binary or ternary or octal when working specifically with base conversion?

How about 101<sub>10<sub>2</sub></sub>? Is 111<sub>111<sub>3</sub></sub> = 183<sub>10</sub> = 183?

---

Related:

- [Why do they call it base 10?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1797577/92515)
- [Name for "decimals" in other bases?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93315/92515)
- [Base ten is called "decimal"; what's the name of numbers in base 15?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101649/92515)

Comment: You just answered your question and then asked it in the next sentence. Why is $101_{10}$ not binary or ternary or octal? The thing here, is that we specify the base in decimal, by default.

Comment: And as for why base ten is default, it's because base ten is our default numbering system, which presumably is because we have ten fingers.

Comment: If you really are worried about ambiguity you can always end the chain like such: $101_{1111111111_1}$ as base $1$, no matter what base your reader assume you wrote it in is always unary. (Please don't do this.)

Comment: This is an interesting observation! It reminds me somewhat of [metalanguage in logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage). Specifically, say we're in the middle of defining the natural numbers $0,$ $1,$ $2,$ $\ldots$ in basic set theory, and we call the reader's attention to something $2$ sentences back. Here, the first usage of $2$ is $2$ in the object language and the second usage of $2$ is $2$ in the metalanguage.

Comment: @orlp Note that you can use any single-digit symbol without ambiguity, because the single digits have the value they have regardless of base (as long as the base is large enough for the digit to exist).

Comment: I have wondered this as well.  An alternative would  be to specify the base in itself but then the subscript would always be $10$ and hence not very useful.  Maybe the base should use a different system such as Roman numerals.  This is not a serious suggestion; the choice of $10$ as the default is arbitrary but very well established.

Comment: Because you will enter a so called *regressio ad infinitum* (latin for  it is a mess) . Indeed you will need to specify in which base you mean the base of the base of the base... back to infinity

Comment: I sometimes write the base in words just to avoid raising this question. For example, $31_\mathrm{eight} = 25_\mathrm{ten}$ (though this particular choice of words ruins a joke).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could indicate the base of the base too, but eventually you need a base-indicator that is specified in some "default" base. We normally use base ten so if nothing else is stated that is what the base that is assumed.

Comment: Do you really assume it's binary if nothing else is stated? (Joke, but partially serious).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, of course. There are 10 kinds of people - those who know binary and those who don't:)

Comment: Actually, there are 10 kinds of people! Those who know binary, those who don't, and those who expected that joke to be in ternary.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the base is always specified in decimal, but it is up to you to change that convention, provided you state it clearly.

The following shorthands are universally adopted: $b$ for two, $o$ for eight, $d$ for ten, $h$ for sixteen.

If you want a system that can denote any base without extra conventions, you can resort to unary:

$$10_{||||||||||||||||}=16_{||||||||||}=51_{|||}.$$

This is why th Babylonians dropped their base $60_{||||||||||}$ numeration ($_{||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||}$).

Comment: Another "convention free" option would be $10_{1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1}$, which is just another way of writing unary, of course.

Comment: @goblin What about succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))))))), more Peanoish ?

Comment: Love it :) $\;\!$